# How to add next available date in stock WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code that's suppose to add a next available date in stock when out of stock. I added the field using custom fields.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'filter_product_availability_text', 10, 2);
function filter_product_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {
    $date_of_availability = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'date_of_availability', true );

    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && ! empty($date_of_availability) ) {
        $availability .= '<span style="color:#e2401c;"><strong>- (' . __('Available from:', 'flatsome') . ' </strong>' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'date_of_availability', true ) . '!important' . ')</span>';
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

[custom fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtLtz.png)

Could someone help me ?

The end goal is to have a field in the product with a date, when out of stock is reached it needs to print that line out with the field value
If I however place it like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'filter_product_availability_text', 10, 2);
function filter_product_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {
    $date_of_availability = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'date_of_availability', true );

    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && ! empty($date_of_availability) ) {
        $availability .= '<span style="color:#e2401c;"><strong>- (' . __('Available from:', 'flatsome') . ' </strong>' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'date_of_availability', true ) . ')</span>';
echo $availability
    }
   // return $availability;
}
```

Then it works however for some reason it repeats, like this:
[repeating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZDAQ.png)

Also if enabled it leaves an In stock label on every product despite being disabled

Comment: Use `$product->get_meta( 'date_of_availability' );` vs `get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'date_of_availability', true );` and don't use `echo` in a filter hook but `return` - 
Also avoid using HTML and inline CSS on a hook where the result returned is a string (plain text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your function appears to output twice is that you are echoing the $availability value without modifying or ceasing return output of woocommerce_get_availability text.

The following should work, as it works on Storefront theme:

```
function filter_product_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {

  $date_of_availability = $product->get_meta( 'date_of_availability' );

  if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && $date_of_availability ) {
    $availability .= '- Available from: ';
    $availability .= $date_of_availability ;
  }

  return $availability;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'filter_product_availability_text', 10, 2);
```

However, if the above fails, you can output with an action hook. In your case, the filter may be failing because of something Bacola developers chose to do with their code. This should output regardless:

```
function filter_product_availability_text() {
  global $product;

  $availability = '';
  $date_of_availability = $product->get_meta( 'date_of_availability' );

  if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && $date_of_availability ) {
    $availability = '<div class="product-meta date-of-avail"><p>Available from: '. $date_of_availability .'</p></div>';
  }

  echo $availability;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'filter_product_availability_text' );
```

Add to your CSS file:

```
.product-meta p {
  color: #F00;
}
```

Comment: IT WORKS! THANKS A BILLION! Really appreciate that you went through so many trials and errors, last thing (its okay if not possible) are we able to style this text with like red or is inline styling out ?

Comment: Yes, updated again. You probably want to wrap the output in the div and p tags either way. You could do inline CSS on the p tag ( style="color:#F00;" ) if it's a severe burden to place the CSS in a file, in which case, you would not require the class "date-of-avail". Best of luck!

Comment: It printed out <div class="product-meta date-of-avail"><p>Available from: 1/06/2022</p></div> in this case, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Indeed - sorry, you'll need to remove the esc_html() (updated above). A great resource for customizing with hooks is the [businessbloomer visual hook series](https://www.businessbloomer.com/category/woocommerce-tips/visual-hook-series/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to comment:

```
echo $availability
```

Code snippets:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'filter_product_availability_text', 10, 2);
function filter_product_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {
    $date_of_availability = '17-05-2022'; // Your custom data

    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && ! empty($date_of_availability) ) {
        $availability .= '<span style="color:#e2401c;"><strong>- (' . __('Available from:', 'flatsome') . ' </strong>' . $date_of_availability . ')</span>';
        //echo $availability
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsNY9.png)

Alternatively, there’s also a built-in setting for this under WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Inventory — you can set when it should be considered “low stock”, and then display a message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGtQs.png)

You could change the wording of the message by using a free translation plugin like Loco Translate ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/ ).

Comment: Hi there, nothing is getting displayed. Also changed to the dynamic value and the static but nothing displaying after removing echo

Comment: It is currently set in WooCommerce when it is out of stock with a threshold

Comment: Also it grabs the date from the custom product field since each product will have different restock times